# Looking for 3D-plot component

Tags: c#, 3d, plot

I'm looking a component that is able to draw 3-dimensional images based on 3-dimensional points.

Example (See 3D Plot): http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=abs%28x%29+%2B+abs%28y%29

In my application I have points containing the coordinates for the x-,y-, and the z-axis.
I'm looking for a usage like this:

```
PlotComponent.Points.Add(x,y,z);
```

The possibility to define the view angle would be nice as well.
Is there any open source component available? (Can't be a commercial license, because the project is a student project)

Winforms Application

Comment: Which technology are you basing this on? Winforms or WPF? Also, do you have a Mathematica license per chance?

Comment: @Gleno: Winforms. No I don't have a Mathematica license

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up using ILNumerics.Net: http://ilnumerics.net/

It has the ability to draw nice 3D-Plots, but the rotating / zoom function is buggy and might result in a buggy redraw.

There is also a problem with disposing / reusing the control that results in NullReferenceException in the internal code of the 3D-Component, after ~10-20 redraws. (We ended up "fixing" this, by an ugly trial and error approach with try / catch and so on)

I posted some pictures of the finished project here: http://www.tomot.de/projekte/c-sharp-funktionsplotter
The second gallery from the top are 3D-plots made using ILNumerics.Net

**Edit Jan 2012**: The developers decided to go commercial: http://ilnumerics.net/forum/index.php?p=/discussion/226/ilnumerics-goes-commercial-

Answer (score 0):

If you have a component for displaying bitmap (or SVG) then you can use [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) plotting library (GPL, LGPL for core) for producing such bitmap (or SVG file) with graphics.