# Where can I find C# source code for visualizing mathematical curves?

Tags: c#, math

Can anyone direct me to where I can download C# source code for visualization of mathematical curves.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Looking for 3D-plot component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307974/looking-for-3d-plot-component)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean drawing one-variable functions, [Zedgraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/) is a very good and well documented library, and it's open source

Comment: Are you using DirectX, OpenGL or something else? You should edit your question adding that information